# Carousel scrollable?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, carousel

carousel scrollable ?

Is there a solution to scroll an image in a carousel ? scrollable, scroll, do not work

thks ...

Code:

```
Ext.define('carousel.view.test', {    extend: 'Ext.carousel.Carousel',


    xtype:'test',


    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
       scrollable: 'vertical,


        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'image',
                html: '<img src=./resources/images/1.png />',
                            scrollable: 'vertical'                   


            },
            {
                xtype: 'image',
                html: '<img src=./resources/images/2.png />'

            }
        ]
    }


});
```

EDIT :

I may have found a solution, but it works on chrome, not on android or Ios, why ?

It works

```
config: {     

        items: [
            {xtype: 'container',

                scrollable: 'vertical',
                directionLock:true,
                items:[
                           { xtype: 'image',                         

                            html: '<img src=./resources/images/1.png />'}
                ]                            
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scrollable : {
     direction : 'both',
     directionLock : true
}
```

Comment: yep scrollable {} was the thing ! thks

Answer (score 0):

According to sencha members on their forums,

```
scrollable : {
    direction     : 'vertical',
    directionLock : true
},
```

forgot to paste here, sorry